# Writing the tag wikis and excerpts

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation

we have already created a lot of [tags](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/tags) and there are also a lot of [meta-tags](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/tags). Most of them have no excerpt/wiki yet.

I am proposing that we have a central list of tags that have no proposed excerpt/wiki or that are currently under review. As I write this proposal only moderators can accept changes to tag wikis/excerpts and I suppose a list gathering all these suggestions would make their life much easier.

**Note:** If this proposal gathers enough support, I will post two community wiki answers containing these lists.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's really no need. Just look at the tags and add excerpts wherever you see fit or whenever you need a tag that doesn't have an excerpt. Creating a tag list here and transferring it to another list when it's pending and tracking what is done and what's not adds a layer of unnecessary management that could be better spent actually doing the work. It's just not needed.

This is a good time to mention that **tag excerpts should describe WHEN and HOW a tag should be used** in relation to this site. Tag excerpts should ***not*** generally be used to define the term of the tag itself, unless it's an obscure acronym or concept that *needs* defining.

Comment: I understand this. I have just written this question after I waited some time for my suggestions for [on-topic] to be reviewed. So I wanted to draw special notice to meta suggestions as I have seen that some main suggestions have already been reviewed.

Comment: Thanks, I assume I can accept this answer to make clear that this is the outcome of my proposal.

Comment: @Blue Tags with no questions associated with them are removed automatically so just delete them from the questions and they should be removed overnight.

Comment: @RobertCartaino "Tag excerpts should not generally be used to define the term of the tag itself" But this can be put in a possible tag _wiki_, right?

Comment: @Discretelizard Yes, tag wiki pages (not the excerpt) are much more free form to use however you see fit. Just don't use it to copy a Wikipedia page (for example). Wiki pages are meant to create something *unique* for this site specifically.

Comment: What is the best practice for creating tag synonyms at this stage, when no user has the rep required to do so?

Comment: There's a FAQ: https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging and some Q&A: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/146949/when-should-i-create-a-new-tag-how-do-i-request-a-new-tag-if-i-dont-have-enoug on SO/SE that we can draw from when creating our own.